# Please allow a few extra edits within a minute of the post before sending Captcha

Tags: feature-request, captcha, spam-detection, time-limit, edits

For one thing, the system would not be spammed by edits,, Also the last edited date does not change if the edit was less than a two or three minutes after the post. I don't think robots are as much of a concern here. It would be more a concern on edits that pull the post to the top by updating the last edit time and of course for creating new posts.